# Android Studio, how do I search in Selected Text, Replace Occurences in Selected Text

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio search function is missing an optiuon to Search/Replace only within Selected Text
Or within the current document, or do replace one by one or replace all,

These options are standard in Visual Studio and Notepad++

I usually have to open the source files in Notepad++ just to do very rudimentary search operations that should be standard in every IDE,

Does Android Studio have those functions? And if so, how can I do a Replace all at once, Replace one by one (where it cycles to the next occurrence, so I can choose if I want to replace or ignore) Replace only within selection, within current document, or the entire solution?

Photos of the locations of the search functions/buttons would be very useful in the answer,

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249274/find-and-replace-android-studio

> I think the shortcut that you're looking for is:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Windows and
> Linux/Ubuntu
>
> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on macOS (IntelliJ
> IDEA Classic keymap)
>
> <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on macOS (macOS keymap)
>
> ref: [source](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/find-and-replace-in-path.html)

Comment: Some people are saying that it is Ctrl + Shift + R on mac, but Cmd just worked for me.